# Viewing large (~1GB) Document, audio or video files using UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

There is a problem viewing large (**at least 1gb**) document, audio and video files in `UIWebView`.

I would like to ask if there any way these large files can be viewed because from the average apple device is only at 1GB RAM thus should not be able to view files bigger than that(not to mention the memory consumption of the OS itself and other background tasks).

I can watch a big(~2gb) movie in iPhone movie player but not in my app when using webview, so I thought that there should be a way to do this but can't find the web for suggestions.

With that it should be possible, so is there any way to do that because webview can't seem to ***handle big files*** as it will surely ***run out of memory***.

I need to be able to pass the file as `NSData` because the file in the device is encrypted and must always stay that way.

This is how I show audio/video files:

```
NSString *contentType = [MIMETypeToFileExtViceVersaConverter convertFileExtensionToMimeType:shareWithObject.fileExtension];

NSString *base64String = [fileData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \
                     <html><head></head><body style=\"margin:0;width:100%%;height:100%%;\">\
                     <video controls height=\"100%%\" width=\"100%%\"> \
                     <source type=\"%@\" src=\"data:%@;base64,%@\"> \
                     </video></body></html>", contentType, contentType, base64String];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

This is for the document files:

```
NSString *contentType = [MIMETypeToFileExtViceVersaConverter convertFileExtensionToMimeType:shareWithObject.fileExtension];

[self.webView loadData:fileData MIMEType:contentType textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Comment: 1 GB of document... you should think over handling the large files... webview is wrong...

Comment: Can you handle with AVPlayer? It can work with stream, will solve your problem of large files, but I am not sure how to work with cryptography with it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I ran out of option, can't pass nsdata to mpmovieplayer for movies and also to QLPreviewController for documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible when using the `loadData` function of UIWebView. We had to limit the size of the document that can be viewed to prevent memory shortage related crashes.

Hopefully in the future there will be a solution for this question, I will move the answer award from this answer to the one with the valid answer to this question